# Writing a function to output WooCommerce's featured products

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am trying to write a function to output featured products so that I can tie it in with Advanced Custom Fields to display more data on the front-end.

```
function featured_courses_query() {
    $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'product',  
        'meta_key' => '_featured',  
        'meta_value' => 'yes',  
        'posts_per_page' => 3  
    );  

    $featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );  

    if ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

        $html_out = '<ul class="products">';

        while ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   
            $featured_query->the_post();  
            $product = get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );

            $course_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
            $course_level = get_field( "course_level" );
            $course_id = get_field( "course_id" );

            // Output product information here
            $html_out .= '<li class="product type-product status-publish no-post-thumbnail first instock featured taxable shipping-taxable product-type-simple"><div class="entry-product"><div class="entry-wrap"><header class="entry-header">';
            $html_out .= '<h4>' . $course_title . '</h4><p>' . $course_level . " - " . $course_id . '</p>';
            $html_out .= '</header></div></div></li>';

        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</ul>'; 

    else : // No results
        $html_out = "No Courses Found.";
    endif;  

    wp_reset_query(); 
    return $html_out;
}

add_shortcode( 'featured_courses', 'featured_courses_query' );
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but when I use the shortcode `[featured_courses]` it outputs what's in the `else`. Is it better to write a custom function like this or edit the WooCommerce file that holds the their shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at how woocommerce created their shortcode to outputting featured products via a shortcode and after researching other posts with queries I have found a solution. Here's an example of how I used it:

```
function featured_courses_query() {
    $meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
    $tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'featured',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   =>  'product',
        'stock'       =>  1,
        'showposts'   =>  3,
        'orderby'     =>  'rand',
        'order'       =>  'DESC',
        'meta_query'  =>  $meta_query,
        'tax_query'   => $tax_query
    );

    $featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );  

    if ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

        $html_out = '<ul class="products x-block-grid three-up">';

        while ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   
            $featured_query->the_post();  
            $product = get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );

            $course_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
            $course_level = get_field( "course_level" );
            $course_id = get_field( "course_id" );
            $course_icon = get_field( "course_icon" );
            $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post->ID);

            // Output product information here

            $html_out .= '<li class="product type-product status-publish no-post-thumbnail first instock featured taxable shipping-taxable product-type-simple"><div class="entry-product">';
            if( $course_icon ):
                $html_out .= '<div class="course-icon"><img src="' . $course_icon . '" alt="' . $course_title . '"></div>';
            endif;
            $html_out .= '<h4>' . $course_title . '</h4><p>' . $course_level . " - " . $course_id . '</p><p>' . $excerpt . '</p>';
            $html_out .= '</div></li>';

        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</ul>'; 

    else : // No results
        $html_out = "No Courses Found.";
    endif;  

    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;

}

add_shortcode( 'featured_courses', 'featured_courses_query' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function featured_courses_query() {
    $html_out = "";
    $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'product',  
        'meta_key' => array(
                    'key' => '_featured',
                    'value' => 'yes'
                    ),
        'posts_per_page' => 3  
    );  

    $featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );  

    if ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

        $html_out .= '<ul class="products">';

        while ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   
            $featured_query->the_post();  
            $product = get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );

            $course_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
            $course_level = get_field( "course_level",$post->ID);
            $course_id = get_field( "course_id",$post->ID);

            // Output product information here
            $html_out .= '<li class="product type-product status-publish no-post-thumbnail first instock featured taxable shipping-taxable product-type-simple"><div class="entry-product"><div class="entry-wrap"><header class="entry-header">';
            $html_out .= '<h4>' . $course_title . '</h4><p>' . $course_level . " - " . $course_id . '</p>';
            $html_out .= '</header></div></div></li>';

        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</ul>'; 

    else : // No results
        $html_out = "No Courses Found.";
    endif;  

    wp_reset_query(); 
    return $html_out;
}

add_shortcode( 'featured_courses', 'featured_courses_query' );
```